# Google Analytics API no result

Tags: node.js, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

#### Question

We're having issues with Google Analytcs v3 API and custom metrics/date ranges. Using start date 2016-01-01 and requesting dimensions ga:dimension1 and 2, we're getting no results. Moving the start date forward to 2018-12-01 give us results. Removing the custom dimensions also give us results.

Custom dimension index 1 was last changed 23 Oct 2017 and index 2 was last changed 25 Jan 2018, according to the web console. That's probably when we created them.

Any idea what we're doing wrong?

#### Base query

```
{ metrics: 'ga:pageviews',
  dimensions: 'ga:dimension1,ga:dimension2,ga:hostname,ga:pagePath',
  'start-date': '2016-01-01',
  'end-date': 'today',
  sort: '-ga:dimension1,ga:dimension2,ga:hostname,ga:pagePath',
  filters:
   'ga:hostname==domain1,ga:hostname==domain2,ga:hostname==domain3,ga:hostname==domain4;ga:pagePath=~/jobs/55432-*,ga:pagePath=~/job-detail-55432-*',
  'include-empty-rows': true,
  'max-results': 10000 }
```

totalResults: 0

#### Without custom dimensions

- `dimensions: 'ga:hostname,ga:pagePath',`

totalResults: 5

#### Start date Dec 1st 2018

- `'start-date': '2018-12-01',`

totalResults: 2

---

Update with screenshot from GA custom report

[image]

Comment: Even without the API, when you use the GA Web UI, do you get any results with those 2 dimensions? What are the scopes of those dimensions?

Comment: @XTOTHEL As far as I can tell, yes. For any specific date ranges?

Comment: Would you mind posting a screen capture of the custom report you've generated with those 2 dimensions?

Comment: @XTOTHEL The custom report above works; I get one row for the page and a column with the number of views. But if I select "Flat Table", I get no results.